# How can I display the page number of a cross-referenced object, but only if the object is on different page?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

I am creating a command called `\fullref{<label>}` that takes a label and outputs the number of the labeled object and name and optionally the page number where to find the object if it's on a page that differs from where the cross-referencing call-out occurs.

Examples:

Let a label `\label{chap_intro}` and a text `… as seen in chapter \fullref{chap_intro}.`.

If they are on the same page, the text will output:

> … as seen in chapter 1.1: "Introduction".

If they are on different pages, the text will output:

> … as seen in chapter 1.1: "Introduction" on page 2.

Here is my command so far:

latex

```
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\ref{#1}: "\nameref{#1}" \ifthenelse{
  \equal{\thepage}{\pageref{#1}} % if the current page and the referenced page are the same
 }
 {} % then do nothing
 { on page \pageref{#1}} % else append "on page …" if different
}
```

Even when on the same page, it displays "on page …".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package?

Comment: I am familiar with nothing, I started using LaTeX 2 days ago. I'll have a look, thank you!

Comment: @Mico it works! If you transform your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: In general, \getrefnumber and \getpagerefnumber will allow you to perform tests on the values (refcount and hyperref packages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and its `\vref` user macro accomplish what your `\fullref` macro aims to do.

The package works with `babel`, and it offers ways to customize what is supposed to be typeset if the cross-referenced object happens to be on, near, or far away from the cross-referencing call-out. This customization works by redefining the macros `\reftextbefore`, `\reftextfacebefore`, `\reftextafter`, `\reftextfaceafter`, and `\reftextfaraway`; see section 5 of the package's user guide for the full details.